# Instantiate a List<class> from textual class name

Tags: c#, class, reflection, types, instance

I would like to know if there is the possibility to instantiate a list of instances from textual class name. 
For example, I have this code below :

```
List<Person> Persons;
```

I would like to have this kind of control on specifiying class name for some objects:

```
string ClassName = "Person";
List<ClassName> Persons;
```

If there is some possibility using reflection, please help me, thank you.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem, what are you trying to do ultimately?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do as you've asked - run it in Linqpad to see the output. The key method is [Type.MakeGenericType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx).

If you give your actual use-case or requirements, I can tweak the code to be a bit more useful for you.

```
void Main()
{
    string className = "UserQuery+Person";
    Type personType = Type.GetType(className);
    Type genericListType = typeof(List<>);

    Type personListType = genericListType.MakeGenericType(personType);

    IList personList = Activator.CreateInstance(personListType) as IList;

    // The following code is intended to demonstrate that this is a real
    // list you can add items to. 
    // In practice you will typically be using reflection from this point 
    // forwards, as you won't know at compile time what the types in 
    // the list actually are...
    personList.Add(new Person { Name = "Alice" });
    personList.Add(new Person { Name = "Bob" });

    foreach (var person in personList.Cast<Person>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(person.Name);
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: What if `className == "SomeClassNameOtherThanPerson"`?  Your code will work only for the `Person` class and not for any other class.

Comment: Everything after the `Activator.CreateInstance` is intended to demonstrate that this is a real list you can add to - since he doesn't explain how he intends to use this list it's intended purely as a demonstration of one way to use it. I've edited my code to make this clear.

Comment: Thank you very much @ChrisDunaway, it helps me, but yes, it will work only with "Person Class", the problem here is that you use "cast" on personList as written " personList.Cast<Person>" but how to cast it without hard code ? Thank you very much again !

Comment: You can't cast it to a compile-time type unless you know the type at compile-time (obviously!!). You are pretty much left to only use reflection methods to manipulate the list. IF YOU GIVE YOUR ACTUAL REQUIREMENTS WE CAN HELP YOU BETTER!

Comment: @RB, I added another example, this is what I need to do, avoid the hard code and to control any object just specify the name of class {entity or repository}, I know that I didn't explained good, sorry and thank you very much